# How to clear an obstruction to run power cable through stud

Tags: electrical, receptacle

[image: in wall]

I've drilled a hole through a stud and hit a very thin metal frame that appears to be a support for dry wall. I'm looking for a recommendation to cut this piece of metal so that it doesn't interfere with the electrical cable. I was thinking that a oscillating multi tool would be ideal (approaching from between the lathe and then bending the metal) but I can't find a depth that is sufficient to cut this. Looking for other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that's a 3/4" hole, you could drill slowly with a 1" (or so) metal bit, and effectively clear the way for the wire.

The agony, of course, is buying that big bit for one use. Maybe this one? http://www.harborfreight.com/silver-and-deming-drill-bit-set-8-pc-61802.html

Cheaper but less effective would be a step drill bit, like this: http://www.harborfreight.com/2-piece-titanium-nitride-coated-high-speed-steel-step-drills-96275.html With this, there's a slight risk of a sharp edge...

PS, I personally despise HF/Princess Auto, but for some single use items, I have to admit they're appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe get an offset tin snip. You could reach back in there and snip above and below the hole, then bend the flap towards the insulation and snip it clear of the hole so no sharp edges will slice the wire insulation jacket.

[image]